# Elastic Search via python gives wrong count

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I’m new to python and I need to get connected to “Kibana” via python. we’re using Kibana 7.4.1. The requirement is to get them just the count (hits).

Due to some restrictions, I need to use Python 3.6 only. I’ve added the “ElasticSearch” & “ElasticSearch-dsl” library.

I’m able to get connected to the Kibana via the client, but I’m getting the wrong hits count.

Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import MultiSearch, Search
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import QueryString, Range, SimpleQueryString
es = Elasticsearch(['host2', 'host2'], http_auth=('usr', 'pass'), port=9200)
s = Search(using=es, index='c*')
s.filter(SimpleQueryString(query="tags:prod AND severity:INFO AND service: finder AND msg:* is processed"))
s.filter(Range(** {'@timestamp': {'gte': 'now-5m', 'lt': 'now'}}))
response = s.execute()
print("Got %d Hits:" % response['hits']['total']['value']) # Always coming as 1000 so this is wrong
```

Can I get some help with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all a little clarification. You are connecting to Elasticsearch and not Kibana (Kibana is a client, like the program you are writing).

You are receiving always 10000 as result, because your index has more than 10000 hits. It is a [documented feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-search-api-query-params). Indeed, since the count computation is expensive in the general case it is performed only when needed. In order to obtain the right number of results you have two possibilities

- to set the query parameter `track_total_hits` to true
- use the [count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).

### track_total_hits

You can add this extra parameter to the search object as reported [here](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html) as follows:

```py
s = Search(using=es, index='c*')
s = s.extra(track_total_hits=True)
<the-rest of your code>
```

### Count API approach

Instead of invoking the `execute()` function, you can simply use the `count()` function:

```py
s = Search(using=es, index='c*')
s.filter(SimpleQueryString(query="tags:prod AND severity:INFO AND service: finder AND msg:* is processed"))
s.filter(Range(** {'@timestamp': {'gte': 'now-5m', 'lt': 'now'}}))
response = s.cpunt()
print("Got %d Hits:" % response)
```

Kind regards